# Yii: Already add or edit record but view not update

Tags: caching, yii

I got a problem about browser cache when I already add/edit record in database. The data in database changed but in view not change. I must press F5 in browser for refresh that page and it'll show updated data.

Please guide to me how to solve this problem, Thanks.

**Sorry I forgot to told you guys, In my application has two part.**

1. Admin part (Backend) for add/edit data. (There's not any problem in
   this part)
2. Front part for show data to viewer (Problem here! After
   add/edit record in Admin part, this part not changed. I must refresh
   page to see update)

*This's my relevant code in Front part.*

In Controller

```
class ProductController extends Controller
{
  public function actionIndex()
  {    
    $products = Product::model()->getProductList(); // use findAll() method
    $this->render('index', array('products' => $products));
  }
}
```

In Model

```
class Product extents CActiveRecord
{
  /*
   *
   * The other code that generated by Gii 
   *
   */

  public function getProductList()
  {
    return $this->findAll();
  }
}
```

In View

```
<html>
<body>

<ul class="thumbnails thumbnails-product">      
  <?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>

    <li class="span3" style="margin-left:0px;">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <img class="img-thumb" src="../images/<?php echo $product->PDT_IMG" />
        <?php echo CHtml::link($product->PDT_NAME, array('product/view/' . $product->PDT_ID)); ?>                       

        <span class="price"><?php echo $product->PDT_PRICE; ?></span>

      </div>            
    </li>

  <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Like you want to get data refreshed automatically without user interaction?

Comment: Please post relevant code. How do you reload your view ?

Comment: Thanks for answer, I just add append question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem has been solved.

I just add

```
header ("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header ("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Everytime that view load, it'll reread page and doesn't keep any cache.

Answer (score 1):

If you want something to update on-the-fly, I think you're looking for `in place editing`.
You could take a look at [this extension](http://x-editable.demopage.ru/index.php) which does that for you.
[Especially this](http://x-editable.demopage.ru/index.php?r=site/widgets#EditableDetailView) part.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

May be this can help you out:
[Real-time display of server push data using Server-Sent Events (SSE)](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/329/real-time-display-of-server-push-data-using-server-sent-events-sse/)

this is server push technique by which we can fetch data in every changes made automatically and also after a certain time.